# How to find records which exist in both tables and all records from left table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables

### Listings

ID | NAME

### listing_users

ID | Listings.ID | userID

I am trying to get all the rows which match with userID I provide and also all the rows which are not present in the 2nd table

for example

## Listings

1 | xyz

2 | abc

3 | def

### Listings_users

1 | 1 | 1001

2 | 3 | 1020

I want to get all listings which matches userID 1001 and also those which are not assigned to any user.
So I want to get results like this

listings with ID 1,2
Listings ID 3 should be excluded because it is assigned to some other user

So far I have used left join but it shows me all the records from 1st table.

This is my attempt:

```
          SELECT listings.*
          FROM listings 
          LEFT JOIN listings_users
          ON listings.listing_id = listings_users.listingId AND listings_users.userId=1001
```

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using correctly a LEFT join in your query, but the condition:

```
listings_users.userId = 1001
```

in the ON clause does not filter out the listings that are assigned to any other user.
Try this:

```
select l.*
from listings l left join listings_users lu
on lu.listingid = l.listingid  -- or lu.listingid = l.id if this is the name of the column
where lu.userID = 1001 or lu.listingid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql then you can use left join to get all matched rows from both tables  and unmatched rows from table first.

`SELECT (*) From listings LEFT JOIN listings_users ON  listings.id = listings_users.listings_id;`

if you want to use with condtion use where key word

`SELECT (*) From listings LEFT JOIN listings_users ON  listings.id = listings_users.listings_id where listings_users.userId=1001;`